# Looping through words in PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a problem to loop through a string word by word. I will have a input string "Sudan China USA Africa" and I have lookup table having 3 rows Sudan, China, USA. So I need to write to PL/SQL function which will loop through the input string "Sudan China USA Africa" for each word from Right to Left (Africa to Sudan in this case) and try to find match from lookup table and it found any matching word (1st occurrence from right, which in this case is USA) it will stop the looping and return the word(USA). So sum it up we have to loop from right to left of an input string word by word and return the 1st matching word available in Lookup table.

Comment: What's the reason behind searching the word from right to left? Did you tried to solve your problem? Can you post your code with current progress?

Comment: Currently I am looking for 1st occurrence of any keyword in the string using instr function. I can't share my existing code as it's in remote machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done is a single SQL query e.g.

```
WITH mydata AS
  (SELECT 1 AS id, 'Sudan China USA Africa' AS string FROM dual
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 2      , 'China Europe Sudan Asia'          FROM dual
  )
   , lookup AS
  (SELECT 'Sudan' AS word FROM dual
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 'China' FROM dual
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 'USA' FROM dual
  )
SELECT t.id
     , max(t.word) KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY t.pos) lastword
FROM (SELECT mydata.id
           , pos.column_value AS pos
           , regexp_substr(mydata.string, '([^ ])+', 1, pos.column_value ) AS word
      FROM mydata
           CROSS JOIN
             TABLE
               (CAST
                  (MULTISET
                    (SELECT level
                     FROM dual 
                     CONNECT BY level <= regexp_count(mydata.string, '([^ ])+')
                    ) AS sys.odciNumberList
                 )
              ) pos) t
     INNER JOIN lookup l
       ON (t.word = l.word)
GROUP BY t.id

        ID LASTWORD              
---------- -----------------------
         1 USA                     
         2 Sudan
```

Answer (score 1):

```
declare

function searchWord(inputString in varchar2) return varchar2
is 

TYPE arrayWord IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(32767) INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
word    arrayWord;
tmpStr  varchar2(32767);
i       pls_integer := 0;
tmp     number;
begin
tmpStr := inputString;
loop
  word(i) := (substr(tmpStr,1, instr(tmpStr,' ')-1));
  tmpStr  := substr(tmpStr, instr(tmpStr,' ')+1);
  if instr(tmpStr,' ') = 0 then
    i := i+1;
    word(i):= tmpStr;
    exit;  
  end if;
  i := i+1;
end loop;

if word.count > 0 then
  for i in reverse word.first..word.last
  loop
    select count(*) into tmp from t1 t where t.word = word(i) and rownum = 1;
    if tmp != 0 then
      return word(i);
    end if;
  end loop;
end if;
return null;

end searchWord;

begin
dbms_output.put_line(searchWord('Sudan China USA Africa'));
end;
```